# How to view TightVNC recordings

Tags: recording, vnc, session, playback, tightvnc

TightVNC allows you to record VNC sessions. It saves them in fbs files. I'm trying to playback these files. There does not appear to be anything that can play these that come with TightVNC. All my searches go to one website, and it isn't there anymore.

Comment: ?what version of tightvnc you use... ?do you use the java version to save the session ?what syntax do you use to start saving (i cant get any examples from the documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RFBPlayer](http://www.tightvnc.com/rfbplayer.php)